# Pandas: Replacing '-' when used as a zero but not when used as a negative

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am reading a csv file into a pandas dataframe.

```
df= pd.read_csv("table.csv", encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
```

I have a column named 'value' which contains '-' when the value is nil.  My aim is to filter out all rows where the value in this column is nil.

However the sign is also contained when the value is a negative.

When I try:

```
    df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace(',', '')
    df['value'] = df['value'].str.replace('-', '0')
    df['value'] = df['value'].astype(str).astype(float)
    df= df[df['value'] !=0]
```

All negative numbers become positive as I am stripping out the negative sign.

However, if I don't convert '-' to '0' then I get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '-'
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: See my answer as I think it is very simple and it completes your filtering in one line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As pointed out by @Allolz, to get rid of your `,` thousands separator, use the `thousands` argument in `pd.read_csv()`:

```
df= pd.read_csv("table.csv", thousands=',', encoding = 'ISO-8859-1')
```

If I understand correctly, the easiest thing to do is to use `pd.to_numeric`, which can convert all non-numerics to `NaN`, which you can then replace with 0:

```
df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df.value,errors='coerce').fillna(0)
```

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'value':['-','-0.5','0.5','-']})
>>> df
  value
0     -
1  -0.5
2   0.5
3     -

df['value'] = pd.to_numeric(df.value,errors='coerce').fillna(0)
>>> df
   value
0    0.0
1   -0.5
2    0.5
3    0.0
```

But if you wanted, you could also use `replace` instead of `str.replace`, to replace full strings rather than substrings:

```
df['value'] = df['value'].replace('-',0).astype(float)
```

Example:

```
>>> df
  value
0     -
1  -0.5
2   0.5
3     -

df['value'] = df['value'].replace('-',0).astype(float)
>>> df
   value
0    0.0
1   -0.5
2    0.5
3    0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to filter out rows with the value 'nil' you can save yourself some steps if I understand correctly:

input df:

```
   Row Value
0    1     -
1    2    -8
2    3     4
3    4     8
4    5     -
5    6   -17
6    7    12
7    8     0
```

This has all your test cases. The filter step is a 1 liner:

```
df.loc[df['Value'] != '-']
```

output:

```
   Row Value
1    2    -8
2    3     4
3    4     8
5    6   -17
6    7    12
7    8     0
```

As you can see it got rid of both instances where value was equal to "-" but kept negative numbers, which saves you from any type of conversions  you are doing upfront... df.loc filters by row for the column 'Value'.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 nil_mask = df['value'] == '-'
 df['value'][nil_mask] = 0
```

this is only set to zero instances where the whole value is '-', will that work?

Answer (score 0):

You could use an apply.
Try:

```
def replace_val(val):
    if val == '-':
        return 0
    return val

df['value'] = df['value'].apply(replace_val)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you are using pandas, you could coerce the strings into numbers and the nulls which are identified through '-' will be forced into NaNs and '-4' will become an integer of -4.

```
test = pd.DataFrame([['-', '-2', '-', '0'],
                   ['3', '4', '-', '-1'],
                   ['-', '-', '-', '5'],
                   ['-', '-3', '-', '4']],
                   columns=list('ABCD'))

test.apply(pd.to_numeric, args=('coerce',))
```

You should get back:

```
     A    B   C  D
0  NaN -2.0 NaN  0
1  3.0  4.0 NaN -1
2  NaN  NaN NaN  5
3  NaN -3.0 NaN  4
```